# Returning null from function F#

Tags: .net, f#, xamarin.ios

I'm attempting to implement the following Swift method in F#:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
     if (flatImages?.count) != nil {
         if ((flatImages?.count)! > 0) {
              let curr_index = (viewController as! FlatImagesContentViewController).page_index

              if (curr_index! < flatImages!.count - 1) {
                 return viewControlerAtIndex(curr_index! + 1)
              }
              else {
                 return nil
              }
           }
        return nil
     }
   return nil

}
```

The idea is that this method returns null in all cases, except one where it returns a `FlatImagesContentViewController` which can be cast to a `UIViewController`.

To do so, I have implemented the following `F#` code:

```
override x.GetNextViewController(pageViewController : UIPageViewController, contentController : UIViewController) = 
    let mutable returnController : UIViewController = null
    if flatImages.Length > 0 then 
        let curr_index = (contentController :?> FlatImagesContentViewController).GetPageIndex
        if curr_index < flatImages.Length - 1 then 
           returnController <- viewControllerAtIndex(curr_index + 1)
    returnController
```

The issue is that every single block in `F#` needs to have a return value, therefore I cannot return from the if block directly, as this would be treated as the return value of the if block, not of the whole function. To overcome this, I have created the `returnController` variable initialised to null and then I return this at the end of the function. Is this the correct way to handle such a use case in F#?

Comment: `!=` is not an operator in F#. "Not equals" is `<>`. However, it looks like the Swift code is really checking if `flatImages` is null indirectly using the `?.` nil-propogation operator. So you should be checking if `flatImages` is null.

Comment: `flatImages` can't be null in the way I designed the F# code, as it is initialised to an empty list. In the Swift version, it is an optional instead, so that additional check isn't needed here. Sorry, I should've clarified this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a mutable return variable won't help here. In F# the built-in types are not nullable, but .NET/C# classes are, such as `string`. It is possible to return a null or a string in different branches. This compiles:

```
if true then
    ""
else
    null
```

If you define your own type in F#, then `null` cannot be assigned to it:

```
type A = { A : int }

if true then
    { A = 1}
else
    null // Error: The type 'A' does not have 'null' as a proper value
```

To fix this you need to wrap your value in an `Option`:

```
if true then
    Some { A = 1}
else
    None
```

Now the type returned is `Option<A>`. An `Option` value must be explicitly unwrapped so that the `None` case is handled:

```
let x = Some { A = 1 }

match x with
| Some a -> a.A
| None -> 0
```

Comment: The `UIViewController` type is part of MonoTouch and Xamarin.IOS, and represents an activity/class/one page of an app in iOS development. It compiles. Would this still be feasible if it compiles like in the case of string?

Comment: I think that will be nullable so you can just have null branches, but you must make sure every `if` has an `else`

Comment: Would it not work the way I have it set up now? Where the only return value is at the end of the function?

Comment: Yes it will work but it's not necessary. A more direct port of the Swift code should work just as well.